# Bivariate distribution that's not a distribution of a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{B}^2)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So I have to show: Every bivariate distribution $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to[0,1]$ has the following properties:

a) $F(\cdot,y):x\mapsto F(x,y)$ is monotonically and right continuous for every $y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $F(x,\cdot):y\mapsto F(x,y)$ is monotonically and right continuous for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I was already able to show this but i'm not sure why they only say monotonically because it is indeed strong monotonically increasing.

b) $\lim_{x\downarrow-\infty}F(x,y)=0$ for every $y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{y\downarrow-\infty}F(x,y)=0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{\substack{x\to\infty\\y\to\infty}}F(x,y)=1$.

I was already able to show this too.

Now the part where i have trouble is this: Show by a counterexample that not every function $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to[0,1]$ with these properties is a distribution of a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{B}^2)$. There's a hint too: For the construction of a counterexample it will be helpful to think about how the probability of a Set $(x_1,y_1]\times(x_2,y_2]\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ can be represented with its distriubution function.

So for the hint: Let $P$ be a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{B}^2)$ and let $F$ be its distribution. Then

$P\left((x_1,y_1]\times(x_2,y_2]\right)=F(y_1,y_2)-F(x_1,x_2)$,

right? So now i have to find a function $F$ that has these properties but also violates the terms of a probability measure. I maybe thought about a function where

$F(y_1,y_2)<F(x_1,x_2)\Longrightarrow P\left((x_1,y_1]\times(x_2,y_2]\right)<0$

but since $F$ is monotonically increasing, this doesn't work. I wasn't able to violate the $\sigma$-additivity of $P$ either...

Maybe you guys have a Tip for me! Thank you so much! Kind regards.

Comment: Try to calculate $\mathbb P( (x_1,y_1] \times (x_2,y_2])$ one more time, you should get something different, which will probably lead you to a counterexample.

Comment: @DominikKutek Thank you for the answer! I thought about it and now have $P((x_1,y_1]\times(x_2,y_2])=F(y_1,y_2)-F(x_1,y_2)-F(y_1,x_2)+F(x_1,x_2)$.

Comment: @DominikKutek I couldn't find a solution...

Comment: I would suggest the following. We want to make our counterexample as easy as possible, so let $F(x,y) = 0$ if $x \le 0$ or $y \le 0$, that is, we will only "adjust" $F$ on the set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x,y > 0\}$. Let us just make it "jump" on "weird" set, that is (for example) $F(x,y) = 0$ for $xy <1$ and $F(x,y) =1$ for $xy \ge 1$ (i.e looking at $x,y > 0$, our $F$ jumps on the curve $y = \frac{1}{x}$). Then, arguing by contrary that $F$ is a CDF, and looking (for example) at a rectangle $(\frac{1}{2},2] \times (\frac{1}{2},2]$ you arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: @DominikKutek Thank you so much!